# Are elements separated in a list with a comma?

Tags: python

If I create a list in python like this:

`list1 = ['a' 'b' 'c']`

or

`list2 = ['a','b','c']`

What is the difference between `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: Have you tried your code? Python implicitely concatenates subsequent string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `list1`'s value would be `['abc']`, while `list2`'s value would be `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Observe:

```
>>> ['a' 'b' 'c']
['abc']
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

This is due to the fact that adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

The above is a quote from the documentation: [String literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

The first example creates a list with one element, `['abc']`. The second creates a list with 3 elements: `['a', 'b', 'c']`.